# How to change the function call based on value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, if-statement, conditional-statements

There are 3 functions imported:

```
import { searchShip, searchLcl, searchFcl } from "services/logisticsService";

searchData = {
  currentPort: currentPort,
  destinationPort: destinationPort,
  date: readyTOLoad,
  type: containerType,  // containerType is geting 1 value among this (ship,lcl,fcl)
}
```

Here I want to call one of those function  based on that `containerType` value. For example:

If I get type value as `ship` then it should be

```
searchShip(searchData).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
})
```

If I get type value as `lcl` then it should be

```
searchLcl(searchData).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
})
```

If I get type value as `fcl` then it should be

```
searchFcl(searchData).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
})
```

Is there any good way to call that search function on that type condition without if else statement because inside it there is very lengthy process to handle response.

Comment: see the duplicate, it is near exact. (make an object with your function names as properties and access them as needed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can define an object that has a {[key]: function} structure.

```
const handlersByType = {
  ship: searchShip,
  lcl: searchLcl,
  fcl: searchFcl.
};

handlersByType[type](searchData).then((response) => {
  console.log(response)
})
```

Comment: Don't forget to check if `handlersByType[type]` exists or is indeed a function. You could use optional chaining for that.